# 500 Internal Server Error in my wamp server while trying to Rewrite URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to rewrite my bulky, ugly url to a neat one which is converting "art.php?id=$1" in to "art/1", but I encounter a "500 Internal Server Error" What shall I do? Can you help me pleeeease?

This is the .htaccess code I used:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule    ^art/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    art.php?id=$1  [NC,L]
```

This is the Error I encountered:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error. More information about this error may be available in the
>   server error log.

Thanks!

Comment: Please note the **More information about this error may be available in the server error log** part. You'll find the exact error message there.

Comment: This rule alone shouldn't produce any error. Most likely, you have other rules or directives as well. Either some other directive or the combination of this and other directives causes the internal error.

Comment: I right clicked on my WAMP icon and go to apache, then apache module and I checked rewrite module. Then the error is gone, but my url is not changed :( still "art.php?id=1" but I want it to be "art/1"

@Olaf I don't have any directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed everything is in the `gallery` folder, which itself is located in the `www` root directory. Then put this .htaccess file into the `gallery` folder as well

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /gallery/

# prevent endless loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# serve real content
RewriteRule ^art/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ art.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

# make pretty URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.+)
RewriteRule ^art.php$ art/%1? [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Dankeschön Olaf. Es gibt etwas Schönes zu diesem Code, at least I see some changes :), but in my url it displays "http://localhost/art/1?id=1" With an error msg: Not Found

The requested URL /art/1 was not found on this server. 
It should be like http://localhost/gallery/art/1

Comment: @B3738 The first one is a missing question mark `?`, fixed. For the second one, I prefixed the pattern and substitution with `gallery`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @ Olaf, well the url is changed in to: http://localhost/gallery/art/1, but the error: "Not Found The requested URL /gallery/art/1 was not found on this server." is still there. It suppose to fetch the data from mysql and display it on the browser, even if the url is changed right? art.php is on my gallery folder and my galley folder is in the wamp/www folder. Man what is wrong with it?

Comment: @B3738 I reverted most of the changes and added a `RewriteBase`. The changed .htaccess must be in the gallery folder too. It assumes that the `art.php` is in the gallery folder as well.

Comment: @ Olaf you are very tolerant - you write the code like three times. Thank you very much. However yet the same error message is being displayed. Vielen Dank! You are so the best! ;)

Comment: @B3738 Then I'm out of ideas. You shouldn't accept my answer, though. Because everybody else thinks your question is solved, which is not the case. And then nobody else will provide a solution.

Comment: @ Olaf Wunderschön! It worked like a charm!! I kinda made some directory changes that was why it was not working. I'm late to thank you, because My CDMA failed and now I'm in internet cafe just to thank you. I thank you very much. Ich habe noch nie Deutschland gewesen, aber Deutsch sprechen. Weil you guys are awesome! You proved it! You're a code assassin!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the server you're on, you might want to set the base for rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /art/
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    art.php?id=$1  [NC,L]
```

that should work just fine

Comment: I right clicked on my WAMP icon and go to apache, then apache module and I checked rewrite module. Then the error is gone, but my url is not changed :( still "art.php?id=1" but I want it to be "art/1"

Comment: Drop the NC then, have it like so:
`RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    art.php?id=$1  [L]`

Comment: Danke Unamata, aber es funktioniert nicht! I don't understand what is wrong with it.